# How to Bind viewModel in adapter while using databinding

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, adapter

**song_item.xml**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>
    <variable
        name="song"
        type=".models.Song" />

    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type=".SongDetailViewModel" />
  </data>

  <TextView
   android:id="@+id/txt_song_name"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
   app:selected="@{safeUnbox(viewModel.currentData.id == song.id)}"
   />

</layout>
```

**SongAdapter.kt**

I am looking for a way to bind the viewModel in **song_item** to my adapter.

- I will need to initialise *SongDetailViewModel*.
- In fragment I could do:

  **private val viewModel: SongDetailViewModel by viewModels()**

But How will I do in that in my adapter:

```
class SongAdapter(
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

 inner class ViewHolderSong(private val binding: ViewDataBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root), View.OnClickListener {

     private fun bindSong(song: Song) {
        binding as SongItemBinding
        binding.apply {
            this.song = song
            this.viewModel = songDetailViewModel <--- here, I don't know how to initialize this viewModel inside the adapter
            executePendingBindings()
            rootLyt.setOnClickListener(this@ViewHolderSong)
            icMore.setOnClickListener(this@ViewHolderSong)
        }
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: Why do want to pass a view model here? View models are supposed to be scoped to a fragment/nav graph/activity. You won't get (and you don't need) any benefits of ViewModel in your adapter. Just pass a simple kotlin class if you really need to. Otherwise you can just emit events from the adapter and handle them in you fragment/activity OR their view model.

Answer (score 0):

You should send `viewModel` created in fragment to `SongAdapter` as a parameter. After that, you can bind it to `song_item`.

Also don't forget to set `lifecycleOwner` to your song item binding for correct observing of changes. You should send it also by parameter to `SongAdapter`.

Your `SongAdapter` should look at the end of the day like this:

```
class SongAdapter(
    private val viewModel: SongDetailViewModel,
    private val lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    inner class ViewHolderSong(private val binding: ViewDataBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root), View.OnClickListener {

        private fun bindSong(song: Song) {
            binding as SongItemBinding
            binding.apply {
                this.song = song
                this.viewModel = viewModel
                this.lifecycleOwner = lifecycleOwner
                executePendingBindings()
                rootLyt.setOnClickListener(this@ViewHolderSong)
                icMore.setOnClickListener(this@ViewHolderSong)
            }
        }
    }
}
```